# Plot surface in gnuplot from datafiles of different length

Tags: gnuplot, surface

I have a file in the form

```
#line A
x1A y1A val
x2A y2A val
...
xnA ynA val

#line B
x1B y1B val
x2B y2B val
...
xkB ykB val

...

#line Z
x1Z y1Z val
x2Z y2Z val
...
xjZ yjZ val
```

with lines of different length (that is `n, k, ... j` are different in general).

I'd like to plot this file in gnuplot as a surface. Is it possible? Any hints on how to get it?

Comment: I'd like to plot "transparent" surface, like `splot 'data.txt' with lines`.

Comment: What kind of surface do you want to plot? In general you can `splot 'data.txt' with lines`, but that doesn't work with different 'line lengths'. To get a coloured surface plot you can try e.g. with `set pm3d ftriangles; splot 'data.txt' with pm3d`, which can handle different line lengths. Usually this draws quadrangles, the non-matching end points of a line with the neighboring line are filled with triangles. Otherwise you might want to try `set dgrid3d` to resample your data to a regular grid.

Comment: There is no way to get such a surface (with a 2D grid), unless you resample your data with e.g. `set dgrid3d`. Because: How should the grid lines be drawn, if the neighboring lines have different number of points?

Comment: Ok. Instead, `dgrid3d` just cut the latest points of the longer lines, or can it do a more refined resample?

Comment: If you have a recent version of `gnuplot` (Maybe 4.4 should already do), then you have different interpolation settings (e.g. `set dgrid3d 100,100 splines`).

Comment: Did that answer you question? If yes, I could prepare an answer, otherwise you should provide more information how the different line length are to be interpreted (is the x and y range the same, but only with different sampling etc.)

Comment: In my case the lines are very accurate, so I don't want to use any interpolation algorithm. I ended to make the orthogonal lines by hand, taking one point from every line in an appropriate way. But more in general I think your idea can be useful, it'd be great if you can prepare an answer. I can't put my own data here because they are quite large.